# bash: Find a directory and create file with content using -exec

Tags: bash

I want to find a directory and create a file with content in the following format, but it's not doing what I want. Any bash expert can help?

`/bin/bash -c "find directory -type -d -exec echo 'some content with new line \n' > /myfile.txt \;"`

Comment: Why do you need `bash -c`?

Comment: Probably `echo -e ...` or `printf`

Comment: @chepner it's part of my make file which is set up this way

Comment: You can't just run `find directory ... -exec printf '%s\n' 'content' \;`?

Comment: @chepner I tried `/bin/bash -c "find directory -type -d -exec printf 'content \n' > {}/myfile.txt \;"`, but having problem create the file in the directory find in `find` cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `-exec` to execute a shell in order to process the redirection.

```
find directory -type -d -exec sh -c 'printf "content\n" > "$1"/myfile.txt' _ {} \;
```

`{}` should be passed as an argument to that shell, rather than being embedded in the shell command, to ensure the shell sees its value properly quoted.

You can make this more efficient by allowing the shell to process multiple files using the `-exec ... +`  form.

```
find directory -type -d -exec sh -c 'for d; do printf "content\n" > "d1"/myfile.txt; done' _ {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have a directory structure like this:

```bash
$ tree
.
└── path
    ├── 1
    ├── 2
    ├── 3
    ├── 4
    └── 5

6 directories, 0 files
```

then

```bash
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "$1" && echo "foo bar" > afile' sh {} \;
```

will result in

```bash
$ tree
.
├── afile
└── path
    ├── 1
    │   └── afile
    ├── 2
    │   └── afile
    ├── 3
    │   └── afile
    ├── 4
    │   └── afile
    ├── 5
    │   └── afile
    └── afile

6 directories, 7 files
```

with the file being created in every directory found.

---

The 2nd "sh" in `sh -c 'cd "$1" && ...' sh {}` is used as `$0` in the shell, and the `{}` argument is `$1`

---

Slightly more efficient, in that it has to spawn fewer shells:

```bash
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
    for dir; do 
        cd "$dir" && echo "foo bar" > bfile && cd -
    done
' sh {} +
```